# Getting error with OpenJPA and Tomcat 8: ...attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, jakarta-ee, openjpa

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The persistence provider is 
attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the
data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name
must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or 
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties 
are available in the configuration: 
"org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@2655aabb".
```

I tried both of the following in my persistence.xml and neither one works.

(NOTE: I checked and the WAR *does* have persistence.xml in META-INF and the openJPA jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestOpenJPAPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/webservice</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also attempted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestOpenJPAPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                    value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbdi"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="java"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="password"/>
            <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Are you sure [MySQL JDBC Connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6) is available at runtime?

Comment: @dic19 Yes, I am able to connect to it directly using `Context initContext = new InitialContext();
   Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
   DataSource db = (DataSource ) envContext.lookup("jdbc/webservice");
   
   Connection connection = db.getConnection();`

Comment: maybe OpenJPA only supports "jta-data-source" and configuring the database using the URL? i.e doesnt support "non-jta-data-source" on its own?